# QuickBlox memory leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

Can someone help me to solve memory leak issue?

QBRTCSurfaceView makes problem but i dont know how to fix it.

```
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/sample-videochat-webrtc/src/main/java/com/quickblox/sample/groupchatwebrtc/fragments/VideoConversationFragment.java

12-16 17:06:23.993 20887-21542/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/LeakCanary:

* com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc.activities.CallActivity has leaked:

12-16 17:06:23.993 20887-21542/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/LeakCanary: 

* GC ROOT com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.QBRTCSurfaceView.mContext

12-16 17:06:23.993 20887-21542/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/LeakCanary: 

* leaks com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc.activities.CallActivity instance

12-16 17:06:23.993 20887-21542/com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc D/LeakCanary: 

* Retaining: 14KB.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have almost finished my chat app. I want to publish it but after fixing memory leak. Maybe its not big leak but i dont like it..